# s3-amazon image CORS issue (Only happened in few browser after 5-8 hours)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, amazon-s3, cors

Currently, I don't know why I keep hitting the CORS error when I tried to get the image that I uploaded **5-8hrs** ago from s3 photos. It's still okay if I get it from **5-8 hrs!?** Here is my config for s3 aws:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>`
```

Here is the javascript code that I try to get the image:

```js
function getData(link){
 var image = new Image();
//  image.crossOrigin = 'use-credentials';
 image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
 // create an empty canvas element
 var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
   canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
 image.onload = function () {
  //Set canvas size is same as the picture
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  // draw image into canvas element
  canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  // get canvas contents as a data URL (returns png format by default)
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = dataURL;
 };
 image.src = link;
}

getData("https://whammybar.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/duy-gmail-com/productImage/20181001/11bba32c-b276-47f4-b1fa-e87b53136bcc.jpg")
```

```html
<span id="test"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the S3 bucket config but how you are rendering the image.

If you open the your image [link](https://whammybar.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/duy-gmail-com/productImage/20181001/11bba32c-b276-47f4-b1fa-e87b53136bcc.jpg) you can clearly see that its accessible.

What you are doing wrong is trying to render image in a `span` element, which is why in your example it shows the image data as base64 string.

Just change your `span` element to an `img` element then set the `img.src` to your `dataUrl`

```js
function getData(link){
 var image = new Image();
//  image.crossOrigin = 'use-credentials';
 image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
 // create an empty canvas element
 var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
   canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
 image.onload = function () {
  //Set canvas size is same as the picture
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  // draw image into canvas element
  canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  // get canvas contents as a data URL (returns png format by default)
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("test").src = dataURL;
 };
 image.src = link;
}

getData("https://whammybar.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/duy-gmail-com/productImage/20181001/11bba32c-b276-47f4-b1fa-e87b53136bcc.jpg")
```

```html
<img id="test">
```

Comment: This error only happened in Chrome. For IE/Safari is ok.
For my example. I just want to show the base64 string on html. This one cannot solve my problem.

Comment: What is the problem? because the image is accessible from the s3 bucket meaning your current config is fine.

Comment: This error only happened in Chrome/safari. Same pc, still work in IE. I don't know what is the root cause cuz same url use another pc with chorme still work.